# FileNotFoundError when using Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()) with Selenium, but this raises and error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/112.0.5615.49/chromedriver'
```

Even though I do have that file in my file system

```
~/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/112.0.5615.49 # ls
chromedriver
```

Why is it so, is it something to do with permissions?